# Recursion with "out parameter" in C#

Tags: c#, recursion

Can I use an `out` parameter with a recursive method? If it's possible, how can I do it with the following code?

```
private void PrepareDir(out List<_File> listFiles,string root,string dirPath) {
    DirectoryInfo dirRoot = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
    FileInfo [] Files = dirRoot.GetFiles();
    dirPath = dirPath.Substring(root.Length);

    foreach (FileInfo file in Files) {
        _File _file = new _File();
        _file.Name = dirPath + "\\" + file.Name;
        _file.Path = file.FullName;
        _file.Size = file.Length;
        listFiles.Add(_file);
    }

    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in dirRoot.GetDirectories()) {
        PrepareDir(out listFiles, root, dir.FullName);
    }
}

private void btnButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    List<_File> Files = new List<_File>();
    PrepareDir(out Files,currAddress, currAddress);
}
```

Comment: That should not be an `out` parameter.

Comment: Consider that your listFiles parameter is passed by reference (as it is a reference type), you aren't actually reassigning the identifer; ergo: `out` is not necessary and the code could work without it in your case.

Comment: @SLaks so it's not possible to use out with a recursive method?

Comment: @MurHafSoz it is possible, but the way you are using it is not necessary, it'll work without it (you'd need to assign the identifier as per the rules of `out`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I decided to rewrite my answer to be more direct about why using `out` is not necessary here. I wrote this to be rather lengthy, because I think the root of your question is more in not understanding the differences between passing by value, passing by reference, and the common confusion between *a reference type* being *passed by reference.* Also note that this isn't explicit to only recursion.

In C#, reference types are passed by value by default. A lot of people can confuse a reference type with passing by reference, but there is an important difference. To make myself more clear, I will refer to a reference type as is, and passing by reference as using the `ref` or `out` keywords.

Passing a reference type by value, because it is a reference to some storage location in memory, allows you to make and persist changes. Take this example.

```
public class MyRefType
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public void Foo() {
    MyRefType type = new MyRefType();
    AddOne(type);
}

public void AddOne(MyRefType type) {
    type.Value++;
}
```

What will happen here, is that the class `type` will now have a value of one. This is the nature of a reference type. If `type` were a `struct`, it would still have a value of 0 inside the Foo method, because a copy was made instead of holding a reference to the object.

Now that I hope you understand the symantics of passing a reference type by value, let's actually talk about passing a reference type *by reference*. This is done using the `out` and `ref` keywords. Make it a point to note immediately that in the CLR, `out` technically does not exist, only `ref` does. `out` is actually represented in metadata as `ref` with a special attribute applied to it, and they ought to be treated the same.

Now let's say we wanted to re-assign our reference type in the `AddOne` method before doing the addition.

```
public class MyRefType
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public void Foo() {
    MyRefType type = new MyRefType();
    AddOne(type);
}

public void AddOne(MyRefType type) {
    type = new MyReferenceType();
    type.Value++;
}
```

Because we are still passing our reference type by value, the value of `type` in the method `Foo` will still be 0. All we did was initialize another storage location in memory, instead of reassigning the original storage location). But we want to actually pass our reference type *by reference*, so we should really do:

```
public class MyRefType
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public void Foo() {
    MyRefType type = new MyRefType();
    AddOne(ref type);
}

public void AddOne(ref MyRefType type) {
    type = new MyReferenceType();
    type.Value++;
}
```

Now the value of `type` in the `Foo` method will be 1. This is because we reused the same storage location that the reference pointed to, instead of creating a new location in memory.

So how does all this apply to `out`? Remember that `out` is the same as `ref` with different usage symantics. The difference is that with `ref` you may leave the method without the reference being initialized, whereas with `out`, you must explicitly initialize it before the method returns.

So in your case of using `out` here, it is completely not necessary because you already have existing reference symantics working for you. I hope this clears up a bit.

Comment: "This causes side effects that the caller of your API might not expect", except that in C# not `out` is required on the caller. So I disagree.

Comment: I had a typo (and now >5 minutes have passed and I can't fix it :) -- "C# `out` is required". You counter that not everyone understands what `out` does, I would disagree still...if it weren't for the very question in which we're discussing this HAHA :) I agree to avoid `out` in general, but 'at all costs' puts too much weight against using it imo. I like your post otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You are misusing the keyword `out` in your code example. Your `List<_File>` is passed as a reference type, and any changes made to that list will affect the caller's list. You only need to pass an `out` parameter when you want to reassign the caller's identifier.

Consider:

```
public bool Foo()
{
  List<int> list = new List<int>();
  list.Add(1);
  Bar(out list);
  return list.Contains(1);
}

public void Bar(out List<int> list)
{
  list = new List<int>();
  list.Add(2);
}
```

`Foo` would return false.

If, on the other hand, `Bar` was like this:

```
public void Bar(List<int> list)
{
  list = new List<int>();
  list.Add(2);
}
```

Then `Foo` would return true. See [`out`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more details.

Your code would work as is without the use of `out`. And, in fact, would not compile - and to make it compile would increase unnecessary complexity to what you are trying to do. Don't use `out` in your case.